# How to efficiently find rows in a very large table that end with a certain value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an indexed (nonclustered) string column (let's just call it 'Identifier') on a table with the following row values:

```
`0000001`
`0000245`
`001`
`AB0001`
```

I want to be able to efficiently return all the rows that have an Identifier ending with a certain number entered by the user. For example, when the user enters `1` then the following rows should be returned:
`0000001`
`001`
`AB0001`

The problem is that using `WHERE Identifier LIKE CONCAT(N'%', @UserInput)` uses an index scan which doesn't scale well, since the table has tons of rows in it (many millions)

How should I efficiently query this data? My first thought is to add a new column that represents the `REVERSE()` of the Identifier column, and then use `WHERE ReversedIdentifier LIKE CONCAT(REVERSE(@UserInput), N'%')` to find the matches using a "starts with"

This doesn't seem like the cleanest solution, but it's all I can think of at the moment. Is there a better way?

Comment: If the user enters `"5"`, should `0000245` be found? And should it also be found if the user enters `"245"`?

Comment: I am not sure why you have accepted this answer. A better approach would be to create a computed column that will have a `REVERSE(Identifier)`. The computed column in SQL Server can be indexed. Then you can run the normal `LIKE CONCAT(@UserInput, N'%')` on the computed column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a column that holds the number component and that column is a number and used that column in an index ... that would be a lot faster.

Comment: Heh. Not sure why I didn't think of this to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: This won't work, unless the number entered is limited to 1 digit. If not, consider `000123`, which should be found if the user enters `3`, `23` or `123`. This "solution" is a degenerate edge case of the proper solution.

Comment: "Identifier ending with a certain number entered by the user." means that it will work with numbers greater than 10. The question is not asking for numbers within a string. The number itself is the key determinant according to the question.